# How can I revise these sentences to be more correct while still keeping the effect?

Tags: editing, grammar

I have written these two sentences:

> Despite her temper, I loved her still.
>
> Or perhaps not despite; perhaps because of.

The second sentence feels grammatically incorrect; how can I revise this to be less awkward-sounding yet still punchy? (The thought continues in the rest of the paragraph, explaining his feelings in more depth; this is the end of one paragraph and the beginning of another.)

Edit: I came back to the paragraph to give context, decided I didn't like the way it flowed into the next sentence, and ended up changing it entirely: "Or perhaps not despite; that would imply I saw it as a flaw." C'est la first editing pass.

Comment: As a writer of fiction, you have enormous license to arrange words in the ways that you hope will affect the reader. I see nothing wrong with your first two sentences: it's the way people speak, after all.

Comment: @PeteWilson Sure, but it sounded wrong to my ear, discordant somehow.

Comment: Retro-closing as per http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic - this used to be accepted as on-topic, but no longer.

Comment: This sort of question is best asked on the English Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second sentence feels grammatically incorrect because it's not a sentence; it's two fragments joined by a semicolon.  That doesn't make it wrong, but that's probably why you're reacting that way.

If you want to keep the fragment style, I would tweak it thus:

> Or perhaps not despite -- perhaps *because of*.

I made two changes there.  First, I emphasized "because of", since that's the key insight that (I assume) you'll build out in the sentences to follow.  The other is that I replaced the semicolon with a dash; a semicolon puts up more of a "barrier" between the clauses (like that one I just used), while a dash is more flexible.  In this case the dash suggests a thought sequence, which seems to fit with what you're trying to do.  (If you want to suggest a more gradual, contemplative process, instead of a dash you could use an ellipsis -- the first thought "trails off" to be replaced by the second.)

Comment: I'd use the M-dash too, although I don't know if "because of" needs to be emphasized so much. I'd have to see the lines in context.

Answer (score 1):

The topic seems informal to me, and lends itself nicely to a more personal, less formal tone. I'm okay with it being not strictly grammatical.

Given that, consider a version that is even less grammatical and more informal:

> Or perhaps not despite. Perhaps because of.

Answer (score 0):

Would you really want it in one pseudo-sentence? When it's not quite a sentence as such, why not have two for the right effect?

> Despite her temper, I loved her still. Or perhaps not despite. Perhaps because of.

Leave some grammar out for the reader's imagination. Even a mark of interrogation showing a sense of 'I really wonder if it is ...' should be nice, I suppose.

> Perhaps because of?

Or, would that be superfluous with *perhaps*? Perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Despite her temper, I loved her still.

Perhaps ...because of it.

This may be a bit too terse for your character, but it adds impact by being more direct.  Without the direct reference to the sentence above, it becomes like an idea that occurs/emerges from the first one.